# react function that returns markup does not display properly

Tags: reactjs

I have a function that creates an unordered list

```
export const functionToCreateMarkup = (data) => {
  var list = document.createElement('ul')
  let labels = {Data1: 'Data 1 name',
    Data2: 'Data 2 name',
    Data3: 'Data 3 name'}
  data.split(' ').map((data) => {
    var item = document.createElement('li')
    item.appendChild(document.createTextNode(labels[data]))
    list.appendChild(item)
  })
  return list
}
```

This is being used in a table with COLUMNS

```
COLUMNS = [{}, {}, {
    header: 'Col Name',
    formatter: (value, rowNum, data) => {
      return functionToCreateMarkup(value)
    }
  }]
```

and this is being used in a Table component in React. But I guess I am not returning the correct value. 
I get the error

```
Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {list}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead.
```

How can I return the correct markup

Comment: You usually do not create DOM nodes manually when using React. But the error doesn't seem to be related to that. What is unclear about the error?

Answer (score 0):

you can't print Object in react 
you should to do something like this

```
import React from 'react'
export const functionToCreateMarkup = data => {    
    const labels = {
        Data1: 'Data 1 name',
        Data2: 'Data 2 name',
        Data3: 'Data 3 name'
    }
    return (
        < ul >
            {data.split(' ').map((data, index) => <li key={index}>{labels[data]}</li>)}
        </ul >
    )
}
```

you don't need VanillaJS to create html Nodes in react